# jQuery: how to trigger a click on document.ready only once?

Tags: hyperlink, cycle

I need to trigger a link, but only one time.

The problem is that the link loads the same page with some additional informations from a GET-function. So the page is in an endless reloading cycle.

This is my (dummy) code:

```
<a id="sendbutton" href="myurl.com/data1&data2">CLICK</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#sendbutton')[0].click();
   });
</script>
```

*PS: This is related to a cron job. This event only has to occur once a day.*

Comment: a little hack could be removing or changing its ID value.. remember that this way you must take care of the stylesheet

Comment: nice thought. but when the side loads again the process repeats itself.

Comment: sure, it depends on what is your target... after seeing your edit about the cron job fired once a day it's clear that the target is wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could verify the URL, and if it contains parameters, do not trigger the link.

```
<a id="sendbutton" href="myurl.com/data1&data2">CLICK</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   if(location.pathname == "" ){
   $('#sendbutton')[0].click();
   }
});
</script>
```

I'm using the global variable "location" which store information about the current URL. Try this!

Comment: "location.href" did it for me =D. Thank you